# How to generate report in excel or pdf format in Groovy?

Tags: excel, grails, pdf, groovy

I am completely new in Groovy/Grails. I have data in my mysql workbench and I am showing it on web page. Now, I want to provide 2 options one is generate pdf for that data & second is excel format.

But, I don't know how to do that. Can somebody please provide me the details that how to accomplish it? Please share some tutorial links or any other details to start developing it from scratch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the documentation to understand how to use it effectively, but there is the [export plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export) which supports creating both Excel and PDF documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to generate simple pdf/excel but when I want to generate it for an entire column.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, but the documentation shows examples of how to customize the output to include only specific properties as columns.

Comment: I mean, I want to generate multiple reports on single click for each table column.

Comment: Can you please check my new question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555958/how-to-generate-multiple-reports-in-grails-using-export-plugin