# How to generate multiple reports in Grails using Export plugin?

Tags: grails, pdf-generation

I am using the [Export plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export) in Grails for generating PDF/Excel report. I am able to generate single report on PDF/Excel button click. But, now I want to generate multiple reports on single button click. I tried for loop, method calls but no  luck.

Reference links are ok. I don't expect entire code, needs reference only.

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks for editing. Can you please help me for the above question?

Comment: I don't think this is really possible. When you make a HTTP request, only a single file can be returned. You could return both reports in a .zip file, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes zip will be ok. If you provide me some sample code for generating reports in zip file then your help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: @Dónal Yes exactly I want to generate multiple files & make them combined in zip file. It would be great if you provide me links or code to achieve that.

Comment: http://groovy-almanac.org/create-a-zipfile/

Comment: I already tried this but It doesn't read file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code for the [ExportService](https://github.com/gpc/grails-export/blob/master/grails-app/services/de/andreasschmitt/export/ExportService.groovy) in the plugin you will notice there are various `export` methods. Two of which support `OutputStream`s. Using either of these methods (depending on your requirements for the other parameters) will allow you to render a report to an output stream. Then using those output streams you can create a zip file which you can deliver to the HTTP client.

Here is a very rough example, which was written off the top of my head so it's really just an idea rather than working code:

```
// Assumes you have a list of maps.
// Each map will have two keys.
// outputStream and fileName
List files = []

// call the exportService and populate your list of files
// ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
// exportService.export('pdf', outputStream, ...)
// files.add([outputStream: outputStream, fileName: 'whatever.pdf'])

// ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
// exportService.export('pdf', outputStream2, ...)
// files.add([outputStream: outputStream2, fileName: 'another.pdf'])

// create a tempoary file for the zip file
File tempZipFile = File.createTempFile("temp", "zip")
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempZipFile))

// set the compression ratio
out.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_SPEED);

// Iterate through the list of files adding them to the ZIP file
files.each { file ->
    // Associate an input stream for the current file
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.outputStream.toByteArray())

    // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.fileName))

    // Transfer bytes from the current file to the ZIP file
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(input, out);

    // Close the current entry
    out.closeEntry()

    // Close the current input stream
    input.close()
}

// close the ZIP file
out.close()

// next you need to deliver the zip file to the HTTP client
response.setContentType("application/zip")
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=WhateverFilename.zip")
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy((new FileInputStream(tempZipFile), response.outputStream)
response.outputStream.flush()
response.outputStream.close()
```

That should give you an idea of how to approach this. Again, the above is just for demonstration purposes and isn't production ready code, nor have I even attempted to compile it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First thing is I have to download files from server & then make it zip

Comment: Thanks.I accepted & up voted your answer. However, It has not solved my full purpose but took me to one step ahead.

Comment: I am not able to download generated zip. Can you please tell me how to generate it using your last 5 lines of code?